# If listboxitem name contains string set it selected

Tags: vb.net, string, listbox, selected

I have a string, which contains words. I loop through these words and if it can be found in my listbox items i want to make it selected.

```
Dim word As String
            For Each word In words 'If it's null then do nothing
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(word) Then
                Else

                    For l_index = 0 To DriveList.Items.Count - 1
                        If CStr(DriveList.Items(l_index)).Contains(word & ":\ drive") Then
                 How to select it???
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If
```

Notice: DriveList.Items(l_index).selected or DriveList.Items(l_index).setselected is not working, there is no member like that. I use VS2012 and my app is running on .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey guys,

this did the trick:

```
  DriveList.SelectedItems.Add(DriveList.Items(l_index).ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

DriveList.Items(l_index)).Selected = True

Should work.

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll